# How to restore IndexedDB from backup file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, backup

I have backup files that have the localStorage data saved in IndexedDB. These files look like this:

[image]

Due to system crash, the browser (Chrome) lost these files and I had to recover them from a backup system. Now I need to restore these files back.

Is there anyway to restore or even be able to read these files?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are a number of questions like this on SO.  Did you try any of their suggestions?  Are you having a specific problem when you try to import the data?

Comment: Other solutions haven't worked that's why I posted a new question. If you have an already posted question that you think might work, I would check it out.

Answer (score 1):

For a good solution, these are not very detailed information.

But the **first hint:**
The name of the folder is *not* `IndexDB` but

```
IndexedDB
```

... please note the additional `ed`.

**Second item:**

If the screenshot is from somewhere inside the `IndexedDB`, it must have been a subfolder within the `IndexedDB`:
*=> The name of that folder is required.*

The IndexedDB is stored within your user-profile. If you didn't change things (created a second user-profile, etc...) the name is "Default". So the whole path is

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\<extension_identifier>\<your-backuped_files>
```

For Chromium it differs slightly:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default\IndexedDB\<extension_identifier>\<your-backuped_files>
```

For more there are more informations required. — Such files can also be found outside the `IndexedDB' within your Chrome profile folder. Their names are generic, the specifier is the name of the folder they are stored in.